# How to add item to list using a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, dictionary

I have a list of reservations, but some ones has a conflict (they are booked in the same day for the same room). In order to solve this problem, I want to create a new list without conflicts. I can change only the room number, but not the reservation date, so I do that in the following method:

```
        public List<Reservation> ResolveConflicts()
        {
            var groupedReservationByDate = _reservations.GroupBy(reservation => reservation.CheckInDate);
            var resolvedReservations = new List<Reservation>();
            foreach (var reservations in groupedReservationByDate)
            {
                foreach (var currentReservation in reservations)
                {
                    var nextReservations = reservations.Skip(reservations.ToList().IndexOf(currentReservation) + 1)
                        .ToList();
                    foreach (var nextReservation in nextReservations)
                    {
                        if (currentReservation.RoomNumber == nextReservation.RoomNumber)
                        {
                            var thread = new Thread(() => ChangeRoomNumber(reservations, currentReservation));
                            thread.Start();
                        }
                    }

                    resolvedReservations.Add(currentReservation);
                }
            }

            return resolvedReservations;
        }

        private void ChangeRoomNumber(IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations, Reservation currentReservation)
        {
            var roomNumber = GetRoomNumber();
            foreach (var reservation in reservations)
            {
                if (roomNumber == reservation.RoomNumber)
                    roomNumber = GetRoomNumber();
            }

            currentReservation.RoomNumber = roomNumber ;
        }

        private int GetRoomNumber()
        {
            var randomNumber = new Random();
            return randomNumber.Next(1, _reservations.MaxBy(reservation => reservation.RoomNumber).RoomNumber);
        }
```

When I do that with a thread, I get a kind of correct list, but is not correct, that returned list should have no conflicts. The same output is produced when I use Thread.Sleep(1000) [Console output with reservation conflicts using a thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAloI.png).

And if I don't use a thread, the returned list is totally incorrect, for the same room are a lot of conflicts [Console output with reservation conflicts without using a thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtLMy.png).

I think is a problem with the thread, the algorithm is correct or at least I hope is correct.

Comment: `And if I don't use a thread, the returned list is totally incorrect, for the same room are a lot of conflicts ` if you have incorrect result without using multithreading, then it clearly means that your algorithm is incorrect. I don't understand why you think that adding multithreading would improve the situation

Comment: Without looking very far, your `ChangeRoomNumber` method is broken. You get a random room number, then iterate over the reservations and generate a new room number if the previous number was already assigned. This is wrong, if you generate a new number then you have to check all the reservations over again

Comment: Thank you! That's the problem, I changed the room number but then I have to check again if there are other conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin, I've solved the problem:

> Without looking very far, your ChangeRoomNumber method is broken. You get a random room number, then iterate over the reservations and generate a new room number if the previous number was already assigned. This is wrong, if you generate a new number then you have to check all the reservations over again – [@Kevin Gosse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869621/kevin-gosse)

The solution is:

```
private void ChangeRoomNumber(List<Reservation> reservations, Reservation currentReservation)
{
    while (IsConflict(reservations, currentReservation))
        currentReservation.RoomNumber = GetRoomNumber();
}

private bool IsConflict(IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations, Reservation currentReservation)
{
    return reservations.Any(reservation =>
        !ReferenceEquals(reservation, currentReservation) &&
        reservation.RoomNumber == currentReservation.RoomNumber);
}
```